# auth0 authentication issue: HttpContext.Current is null. This code path is only valid when in the execution context of ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, auth0, asp.net-authentication

I am using auth0 for authentication, roles and permission in my application. I am following below tutorial to implement auth0 in my application,

> https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet

It created login screen for me, After giving email-id and password it navigates to LoginHandler.ashx. and it shows below error page.

[image]

I am getting token, userid and other information but how to resolve this error in handler?

Comment: Can you provide more information about how you're hosting this code (IIS, IIS Express)? Which .NET framework version are you targetting?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015, Framework 4.6.  And i am working on remote system.

Comment: For hosting I am using IIS Express

Comment: Here's a few suggestions. If the rest of the application also makes uses of ASP .NET and there's no issues when accessing those pages, can you create another Generic Handler (`*.ashx`) which just outputs if `HttpContext.Current` is `null` or not. Depending on this we may understand if it's related to all `*.ashx` or just that one. If the login page is just static HTML+JS you can also create a Web Forms or MVC view as the login page and see if accessing HTTP context there also triggers the issue.

Comment: Bydefault auth0 adding async methods in handler, And so HttpContext.Current was not accessible. I removed Async methods. As of now working...

Comment: Glad you got this sorted. When this happens you should post the solution as an answer on your own question and mark it as accepted; it's what SO docs recommend and it also makes it easier for others to find the solution to the problem.

Comment: Posted (Y)... Thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution, If anyone facing same problem,

```
public class LoginCallback : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
            {
                AuthenticationApiClient client = new AuthenticationApiClient(
                    new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:Domain"])));

                var token = client.ExchangeCodeForAccessTokenAsync(new ExchangeCodeRequest
                {
                    ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:ClientId"],
                    ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:ClientSecret"],
                    AuthorizationCode = context.Request.QueryString["code"],
                    RedirectUri = context.Request.Url.ToString()
                });

                var profile = client.GetUserInfoAsync(token.Result.AccessToken);

                var user = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("name", profile.Result.UserName ?? profile.Result.Email),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("email", profile.Result.Email),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("family_name", profile.Result.LastName),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("given_name", profile.Result.FirstName),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("nickname", profile.Result.NickName),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("picture", profile.Result.Picture),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("user_id", profile.Result.UserId),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("id_token", token.Result.IdToken),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("access_token", token.Result.AccessToken),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("refresh_token", token.Result.RefreshToken),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("connection", profile.Result.Identities.First().Connection),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("provider", profile.Result.Identities.First().Provider)
                };

                // NOTE: Uncomment the following code in order to include claims from associated identities
                profile.Result.Identities.ToList().ForEach(i =>
                {
                    user.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(i.Connection + ".access_token", i.AccessToken));
                    user.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(i.Connection + ".provider", i.Provider));
                    user.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(i.Connection + ".user_id", i.UserId));
                });

                // NOTE: uncomment this if you send roles
                 user.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(ClaimTypes.Role, profile.Result.ProviderAttributes["roles"]));

                // NOTE: this will set a cookie with all the user claims that will be converted 
                //       to a ClaimsPrincipal for each request using the SessionAuthenticationModule HttpModule. 
                //       You can choose your own mechanism to keep the user authenticated (FormsAuthentication, Session, etc.)
                FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CreateSessionCookie(user);

                if (context.Request.QueryString["state"] != null && context.Request.QueryString["state"].StartsWith("ru="))
                {
                    var state = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(context.Request.QueryString["state"]);
                    context.Response.Redirect(state["ru"], true);
                }


                context.Response.Redirect("/");

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue (.NET 4.5), my async handler was working until I added following row to `Web.config`:

```
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />
```

I had to replace all `await`s with `.Result` and implement not async IHttpHandler interface in order to get everything working back. I could not remove setting from config since I needed it for `Page.RegisterAsyncTask`

Maybe it helps someone